# Open one of the folders included in Windows Library

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I include folders in Windows Library, it makes them easier to be searched in and it improves my ability to open favorite files.

However, when I want to save a file in Library, or copy it there, it the system often system fails to determine which of the included folders are the file target.

Is there some trick to either determine the action's target or jump from the Library to one of its children?

Also, sometimes I want to access the directory above the one in the Library. E.g.:

- Library path: `Libraries\programing\htdocs`
- Real path: `D:\very\long\path\xampp\htdocs`
- Desired path: `D:\very\long\path\`

It would be great if there was some shortcut to turn the Library path into a real path.

Comment: So why not right-click the folder under the Library and select *Open folder location*?

Comment: This, on the countrary throws me in the parent folder. But it is usefull too, thank you.

Comment: Nope, on my machine, it jumped to `D:\very\long\path\xampp` and highlighted `htdocs` in the Explorer window.

Comment: You're right, so you only need to go up one level to arrive at the `path` folder, or double-click the highlighted `htdocs` to open that instead. Again, what's the problem? You want to somehow jump from `Libraries\programing\htdocs` *directly* to `D:\very\long\path`?

Comment: Use RAD IDE at web progect. http://netbeans.org/features/index.html NetBeans 7.2 ...

Answer (score -1):

[Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/download.php?l=en)  freeware.

Alt+F12 = Folders history, Alt+F11 = file view history.

[image: Far Manager 2]

Comment: This is definitelly **not** an answer to my question. I was asking how to do the task using windows explorer. This software looks like weaker alternative of old Norton Commander.

Comment: I think this solution will suit many. Write the extension to the windows explorer, and everyone will be happy.